# Sending a particular data type to a SOAP server - base64binary

Tags: php, soap

I am trying to upload a text file of data to a soap server with a function called BulkLoadContacts. The request requires a value called

`<ImportFileStream>base64Binary</ImportFileStream>`

I am creating a file, then querying my database, writing to the file, then connecting to their soap server, then sending my request.

Here is a snippit of my code:

```
    $file = 'tempfile.txt';
$handle = fopen($file, 'w') or die ('Cannot open file: ' . $file);

$list = dbExec("select * from listrak_upload");


foreach ($list as $l){

    $data = $l['email'] . "|" . $l['First_Name'] . "|" . $l['Last_Name'];

    fwrite($handle, $data);
}
$ap_param = array( 
    'ListID'    => (integer) 252403,
    'WSImportDirectives'    => array(
        'ImportTypeEnum'        => 'AddSubscribers',
        'ImportProfileTypeEnum' => 'Overwrite',
        'FileName'              => '',
        'HasColumnNames'        => true,
        'FileName'              => $file,
        'FileDelimiter'         => '|',
    ),
    'fileMappings'  => array(
        'WSFileMappings'    => array(
            'FileColumn'            => 0,
            'IsEmailAddressColumn'  => true,
            'AttributeID'           => 'email',
        ),
),
        'ImportFileStream' => $handle
    );

try {
    $return = $soapClient->__soapCall("BulkLoadContacts",array('parameter' => $ap_param));
    var_dump($return);
}
catch(SoapFault $fault){
    var_dump($fault);
}
```

Here is a code example from the documentation:

```
Byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Temp\\ImportFiles\\TestImportFileWithProfile.txt");
```

Any ideas how to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
$fileName = "test.txt";
$rawFile = fread(fopen($fileName, "r"), filesize($fileName));
$B64File = base64_encode($rawFile)
```

In the param array:

```
'ImportFileStream' => $B64File
```

Maybe PHP client SOAP engine encodes to B64 automatically. If this is the case, comment `$B64File = base64_encode($rawFile)` and send `$rawFile` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have no need to write your data to file - just pass it directly

```
$list = dbExec("select * from listrak_upload");

foreach ($list as $l){
    $data = $l['email'] . "|" . $l['First_Name'] . "|" . $l['Last_Name'];
}
$ap_param = array( 
    'ListID'    => (integer) 252403,
    'WSImportDirectives'    => array(
        'ImportTypeEnum'        => 'AddSubscribers',
        'ImportProfileTypeEnum' => 'Overwrite',
        'FileName'              => '',
        'HasColumnNames'        => true,
        'FileName'              => $file,
        'FileDelimiter'         => '|',
    ),
    'fileMappings'  => array(
        'WSFileMappings'    => array(
            'FileColumn'            => 0,
            'IsEmailAddressColumn'  => true,
            'AttributeID'           => 'email',
        ),
),
        'ImportFileStream' => $data
    );

try {
    $return = $soapClient->__soapCall("BulkLoadContacts",array('parameter' => $ap_param));
    var_dump($return);
}
catch(SoapFault $fault){
    var_dump($fault);
}
```

If SOAP client does not encodes data into base64 automatically, you need to also add this:

```
$data = base4_encode($data);
```